# C++Builder 10.3.3で、macOS 32bit/Mojaveにデプロイしたい。

Tags: c++, macos, rad-studio

C++Builder 10.3.3 Communityで、macOS 32bitをデプロイしようとしたら、上手くいきませんでした。64ビットでは動かないので、Big Sur / Catalinaは候補から外して、Mojaveで試しました。XCodeのバージョンが関係あるらしいので、Command Line Toolsといずれも10.1にしました。しかし、エラーと警告が多数出て、ブランクのプロジェクトでも実行できません。ご助力願えないでしょうか。

1．一つ目のエラーは、malloc/malloc.hにファイルがあるために、PAServerを介してファイルをインポートできなかったものと思われます。手動でmallocディレクトリをコピーしたらエラーが消えました。

```
[bccosx エラー] stdlib.h(128): E2209 インクルード ファイル 'malloc/_malloc.h' を開けません
  詳細な解析情報
    Project14.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\fmx\fmx.h
    fmx.h(25): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\System.hpp
    System.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\sysmac.h
    sysmac.h(83): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks\CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h
    CoreFoundation.h(18): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\crtl\assert.h
    assert.h(4): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk\usr/include/assert.h
    assert.h(44): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\crtl\stdlib.h
    stdlib.h(24): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk\usr/include/stdlib.h
```

2．二つ目のエラーは64ビット環境を32ビットコンパイル環境にインポートしてしまったためではないかと、エンバカデロさまには言われました。

```
[bccosx エラー] time.h(71): E2324 数値定数が大きすぎる
  詳細な解析情報
    Project14.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\fmx\fmx.h
    fmx.h(25): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\System.hpp
    System.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\sysmac.h
    sysmac.h(83): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks\CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h
    CoreFoundation.h(60): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks\CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h
    CFPropertyList.h(17): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks\CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h
    CFStream.h(20): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/usr/include\dispatch/dispatch.h
    dispatch.h(50): #include C:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/usr/include\dispatch/time.h
```

ソースコードを見ると、

```
#ifndef __DISPATCH_TIME__
#define __DISPATCH_TIME__

#ifndef __DISPATCH_INDIRECT__
#error "Please #include <dispatch/dispatch.h> instead of this file directly."
#include <dispatch/base.h> // for HeaderDoc
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

// <rdar://problem/6368156&7563559>
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
#include <mach/clock_types.h>
#endif

DISPATCH_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

#ifdef NSEC_PER_SEC
#undef NSEC_PER_SEC
#endif
#ifdef USEC_PER_SEC
#undef USEC_PER_SEC
#endif
#ifdef NSEC_PER_USEC
#undef NSEC_PER_USEC
#endif
#ifdef NSEC_PER_MSEC
#undef NSEC_PER_MSEC
#endif
#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000ull
#define NSEC_PER_MSEC 1000000ull
#define USEC_PER_SEC 1000000ull
#define NSEC_PER_USEC 1000ull

__BEGIN_DECLS

struct timespec;

/*!
 * @typedef dispatch_time_t
 *
 * @abstract
 * A somewhat abstract representation of time; where zero means "now" and
 * DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER means "infinity" and every value in between is an
 * opaque encoding.
 */
typedef uint64_t dispatch_time_t;

enum {
    DISPATCH_WALLTIME_NOW DISPATCH_ENUM_API_AVAILABLE
            (macos(10.14), ios(12.0), tvos(12.0), watchos(5.0)) = ~1ull,
};

#define DISPATCH_TIME_NOW (0ull)
#define DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER (~0ull)
```

とあります。解決策は見つかりませんでしたが、似たような症例は2018年に中国語のサイトで報告されています。
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=ja&u=http://snoopymemory.blogspot.com/2018/

3．以降その他多数。（2．がまず解決出来ていないので、ソースコードは省略）

```
[bccosx エラー] CGPath.h(391): E2040 宣言が正しく終了していない
  詳細な解析情報
[bccosx エラー] CGPath.h(393): E2303 型名が必要
  詳細な解析情報
[bccosx エラー] CGPDFArray.h(103): E2040 宣言が正しく終了していない
  詳細な解析情報
[bccosx エラー] CGPDFArray.h(113): E2303 型名が必要
[bccosx エラー] CGPDFDictionary.h(116): E2040 宣言が正しく終了していない
[bccosx エラー] CGPDFDictionary.h(126): E2303 型名が必要
[bccosx エラー] Carbon.h(34): E2209 インクルード ファイル 'CarbonSound/CarbonSound.h' を開けません
[bccosx エラー] Carbon.h(49): E2209 インクルード ファイル 'NavigationServices/NavigationServices.h' を開けません
[bccosx エラー] cstdlib(55): E2272 識別子が必要
[bccosx エラー] cstdlib(56): E2272 識別子が必要
[bccosx エラー] cstdlib(57): E2272 識別子が必要
[bccosx エラー] cstdlib(59): E2272 識別子が必要
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(385): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::int_type' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(136): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::int_type' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(391): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::assign(wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(141): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::assign(wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(396): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::eq(const wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(146): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::eq(const wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(401): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::lt(const wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(151): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::lt(const wchar_t &,const wchar_t &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(407): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::compare(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(156): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::compare(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(414): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const wchar_t *)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(167): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const wchar_t *)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(421): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::copy(wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(176): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::copy(wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(429): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::find(const wchar_t *,unsigned long,const wchar_t &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(187): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::find(const wchar_t *,unsigned long,const wchar_t &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(436): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::move(wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(197): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::move(wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,unsigned long)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(443): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::assign(wchar_t *,unsigned long,wchar_t)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(212): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::assign(wchar_t *,unsigned long,wchar_t)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(454): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::to_int_type(const wchar_t &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(227): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::to_int_type(const wchar_t &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(465): E2238 'char_traits<wchar_t>::eof()' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(238): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<wchar_t>::eof()' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(486): E2238 'char_traits<char>::assign(char &,const char &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(141): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::assign(char &,const char &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(491): E2238 'char_traits<char>::eq(const char &,const char &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(146): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::eq(const char &,const char &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(496): E2238 'char_traits<char>::lt(const char &,const char &)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(151): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::lt(const char &,const char &)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(502): E2238 'char_traits<char>::compare(const char *,const char *,unsigned long)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(156): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::compare(const char *,const char *,unsigned long)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(509): E2238 'char_traits<char>::length(const char *)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(167): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::length(const char *)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(516): E2238 'char_traits<char>::copy(char *,const char *,unsigned long)' の宣言が複数存在します
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(176): E2344 一つ前の 'char_traits<char>::copy(char *,const char *,unsigned long)' の定義位置
[bccosx エラー] iosfwd(176): E2228 エラーあるいは警告が多すぎる
```

Comment: 二つ目のエラー、「[bccosx エラー] time.h(71): E2324 数値定数が大きすぎる」については、ファイルC:\Users\makot\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\commandlinetools.sdk/usr/include\dispatch/time.h の内容を確認すべきだと思います。
質問者が問題を見つけられないのであれば、time.hファイルの内容を質問に追加してください。そうすれば、解決方法を回答してくれる人が居るかもしれません。

Comment: Project14.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\fmx\fmx.h
fmx.h(25): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\System.hpp
System.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\rtl\sysmac.h
CoreFoundation.h(18): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\crtl\assert.h
assert.h(44): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\osx\crtl\stdlib.h
の５か所で、32bit版のコードが入っているパス(program files (x68)にあるヘッダファイルがincludeされています。

何故、”Embarcadero”を含むパスが、OneDriveno

Comment: time.hのコピーライトに引っかかりそうだったので、抜粋しました。しかし、抜粋範囲を（コメントを除いて）エラーが出た範囲までに拡張すると次のようになります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。編集してコード範囲を追加しました。